# Getting error while installing sass

Tags: cmd, sass, rubygems

I am trying to install sass on my Windows 10 PC using cli by typing command.
gem install sass
But after little delay it throws below error.

ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Ruby is installed in my PC version is:
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x64-mingw32]

Gem version is 2.7.3

Comment: May be these command might work  `gem source -a http://rubygems.org/` `gem install sass`

Comment: Thank you @DayOne for your comment it was proxy that was blocking the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing all the sources first by running the below command:

`gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/`

If the error persists, try removing the proxy. Your proxy server might be blocking the request.